# SSIS failure flow in SQL Job history

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I have an SSIS solution that inserts content of .csv files into my database. The happy path scenario works great. However, some of the database fields are required. If I, for example, let my solution load an empty .csv file with not nullable fields in the database, the solution will fail, ofcourse. I have used the SSIS failure flow to put these files into a seperate folder. This works fine. When the package finishes, the package finishes and says it completed with errors. This translates to a failed job in the SQL Server agent. The job however did exactly what I wanted: process the valid files and archive the invalid files.

My question is, is there any way I can tell SSIS it's done the right thing and it shouldn't return an error on finish?

Thanks in advance. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

From Agent Job you can try, In the **Job Step Properties** dialog box, select the **Advanced** page

[image]

**OR**

You can ignore the failure from the OnError property of the task:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also go to the task that is causing the package to fail, and change its `FailPackageOnFailure` property to "False".